# How to if id exist from one model to another model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have user and playerteam model. when a certain team picks up a user for their team. Then it stores in a playerteam model like team_id and player_id.(player_id is a user_id); 
now i want to show only those user who are not in playerteam model.
For that i have passed

```php
User::with('playerTeam)->get()
```

in a blade file. It shows all the users but i want to show only those users whose id is not in playerteam model.
**these are the code i have tried**
in user model

```php
public function playerTeam()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PlayerTeam::class,'player_id');
}
```

### Controller

```php
$data['users'] = User::with('playerTeam')->get();
$data['playerteam'] = PlayerTeam::get();
return view('page',$data);
```

So, how do i show users that are not in playerteam model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `doesntHave` or `whereDoesntHave`

```
$data['users']  = User::whereDoesntHave('playerTeam', function ($query) {
    $query->where('column', 'value');
})->get();
```

Or even simpler

```
$data['users']  = User::doesntHave('playerTeam')->get();
//...
```

Check docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Answer (score 1):

You can use eloquent `doesntHave` method like this.

```
User::doesntHave('playerTeam)->get();
```

It will return all user which don't have a playerTeam relationship.

read docs here  [laravel doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Answer (score 1):

```php
   $users = User::doesntHave('playerTeam')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

**use Callback Function**

use `whereDoesntHave`

```
$data['users']  = User::whereDoesntHave('playerTeam', function ($query) {
    $query->where('column', 'value');
})->get();
```

Refer Following Link

[whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Comment: Hope its Work!!.